# How to transfer a call in Angular Web App using twilio javascrict voice sdk?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, twilio, twilio-api

In my Application there is requirement of call rcording and call transfering,I have implemented outbond call where Provider can call their patient phone number. Suppose Provider A calls Patient P1 now after sometim Provider A transfer this call to Provider B , Once Provider B and Patient P1 is connected then Provider A should automatically dropped. I have trial account of Twilio and i have implemented outbond call, where Provider can initiate call.

I have tried below code. but i do not know what can be done for call recording and call transfering.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
console.log(this.data);
this.patientName = this.data.patientName;
this.phoneNumber = this.data.patientPhoneNumber;
this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
let self = this;
console.log(this.data.patientName);
this.authService.getRequest('audiocall/twilio/token', null).subscribe((data) =\> {
try {
this.device = Twilio.Device.setup(data\['data'\], {
debug: false,
closeProtection: true
});
this.setupHandlers(this.device);
setTimeout(function () {
this.iserror = false;
self.callCustomer();
}, 500);
} catch (err) {
this.dialogRef.close();
//this.modalService.dismissAll();
if (err.error && err.error.message) {
this.toastr.error(err.error.message);
}
}
});
}
setupHandlers(device) {
let self = this;

        device.on('ready', (_device) => {
            console.log('Ready to call');
        });
    
        device.on('error', (error) => {
            console.error('ERROR: ' + error.message);
            this.iserror = true;
      if (error.error && error.error.message) {
        this.toastr.error(error.error.message);
      }
      this.dialogRef.close()
            //this.modalService.dismissAll();
        });
    
        device.on('connect', (connection) => {
            console.log(connection);
            if ('patientPhoneNumber' in connection.message) {
                this.callStartTime = new Date();
            }
            this.addCallStatus(connection);
        });
    
        device.on('disconnect', (connection) => {
            setTimeout(function () {
                self.callEndTime = new Date();
                self.addMessageCenterData();
                let formData = {
                    'status' : 'COMPLETED',
                    'voiceCallLogId' : self.voiceCallLogId,
                    'callEndTime' : self.callEndTime,
                    'callSid': connection.parameters.CallSid
                }
                self.updateCallStatus(formData);
        this.dialogRef.close()
                //self.modalService.dismissAll();
            }, 500);
        });
    
        device.on('hangup', (connection) => {
            this.callEndTime = new Date();
        });
    }
    
    
    callCustomer() {
        var params = { patientPhoneNumber: '+91' + this.phoneNumber };
        this.device.connect(params);
    }

endCall() {
this.device.disconnectAll();
this.dialogRef.close();
}

    
    close() {
    this.dialogRef.close()
        //this.modalService.dismissAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't drop full code files of that size into questions here. This will signifiantly lower the chance that you will receive a helpful answer.  This [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) explains how to ask good questions.

They should be as short and concise as possible and ideally have a minimal code example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update, i have short my question code, most of the time people asked for full code reference that's why i have put all code, Can you tell me how can i modify my code to get call recording and call transfer feature, Provider A and Provider B has the same number which is provided by twilio.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still confused. You used the C# tag even though the code in in JS and uses the Twilio Client SDK. Also, if you want to transfer a call, this needs to be orchestrated in your backend by adding another participants to a conference call. Maybe this [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/warm-transfer-nodejs-express) helps you

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my scenario is different, I have a web application developed in Angular 14, which has 3 types of Users, 1 Admin,2 Providers, and 3 Nurses. In my Web Application, only outbound calls will be performed,  I have trial account of Twilio where i have configured Twilio number , Suppose there is Two Nurses ,A nad B , If Nurse A call patient P1 after a few time Nurse A wants to Nurse B, Now my question is how can Nurse A call to Nurse B, Cause for outbound call there is 1 number provided by twilio.

Comment: Sounds like you need a Conference call as mentioned in the linked blog post