# How to do call recording and call transfer using twilio javascript sdk in Angular with .Net Core Backend?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

In my Application there is requirement of call recording and call transferring.I have implemented outbound call where Provider can call their patient phone number. Suppose Provider A calls Patient P1 now after sometime Provider A transfer this call to Provider B, Once Provider B and Patient P1 is connected then Provider A should automatically be dropped. I have trial account of Twilio and I have implemented outbound call, where Provider can initiate call.

I have tried below code. but I do not know what can be done for call recording and call transferring
What required in Backend and what changes can be done here in my Angular APP, I am using Twilio Client JavaScript version 1.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, HostListener, Inject, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from '../../services/common.service';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import \* as moment from 'moment';
import { CommonModalComponent } from '../../modals/common-modal/common-modal.component';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

declare const Twilio: any;
@Component({
selector: 'app-voice-call',
templateUrl: './voice-call.component.html',
styleUrls: \['./voice-call.component.scss'\]
})
export class VoiceCallComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() selectedPatient;
@Output() updateUserList = new EventEmitter();
patientName: string;`your text`
phoneNumber: any;
connection: any = null;
device: any;
time: number = 0;
display;
interval;
callStartTime: Date;
callEndTime: Date;
user: any;
iserror: boolean = false;
voiceCallLogId: any;
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', \['$event'\]) unloadHandler(event: Event) {
let result = confirm(
'Reloading will disconnect call. do you want to reload page?'
);
if (!result) {
event.returnValue = false; // stay on same page
}
}
constructor(
private dialogRef: MatDialogRef\<CommonModalComponent\>,
private authService: ApiService,
private toastr: ToastrService,
private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
private commonService: CommonService,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
console.log(this.data);
this.patientName = this.data.patientName;
this.phoneNumber = this.data.patientPhoneNumber;
this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
let self = this;
console.log(this.data.patientName);
this.authService.getRequest('audiocall/twilio/token', null).subscribe((data) =\> {
try {
this.device = Twilio.Device.setup(data\['data'\], {
debug: false,
closeProtection: true
});
this.setupHandlers(this.device);
setTimeout(function () {
this.iserror = false;
self.callCustomer();
}, 500);
} catch (err) {
this.dialogRef.close();
//this.modalService.dismissAll();
if (err.error && err.error.message) {
this.toastr.error(err.error.message);
}
}
});
}
setupHandlers(device) {
let self = this;

        device.on('ready', (_device) => {
            console.log('Ready to call');
        });
    
        device.on('error', (error) => {
            console.error('ERROR: ' + error.message);
            this.iserror = true;
      if (error.error && error.error.message) {
        this.toastr.error(error.error.message);
      }
      this.dialogRef.close()
            //this.modalService.dismissAll();
        });
    
        device.on('connect', (connection) => {
            console.log(connection);
            if ('patientPhoneNumber' in connection.message) {
                this.callStartTime = new Date();
            }
            this.addCallStatus(connection);
        });
    
        device.on('disconnect', (connection) => {
            setTimeout(function () {
                self.callEndTime = new Date();
                self.addMessageCenterData();
                let formData = {
                    'status' : 'COMPLETED',
                    'voiceCallLogId' : self.voiceCallLogId,
                    'callEndTime' : self.callEndTime,
                    'callSid': connection.parameters.CallSid
                }
                self.updateCallStatus(formData);
        this.dialogRef.close()
                //self.modalService.dismissAll();
            }, 500);
        });
    
        device.on('hangup', (connection) => {
            this.callEndTime = new Date();
        });
    }
    
    addCallStatus(connection) {
        let formData = {
            'physicianId': this.user.userId,
            'patientId': this.selectedPatient.patientId,
            'callStartTime': this.callStartTime,
            'treatmentrequestId': this.selectedPatient.treatmentRequestId,
            'callSid': connection.parameters.CallSid
        }
        this.authService.postRequestWithFormData('audiocall/twilio/add', formData).subscribe((res) => {
            if(res['status']) {
                this.voiceCallLogId = res['data'];
            }
            if (!res['status']) {
        this.toastr.error(res['message']);
                
            }
        });
    }
    
    updateCallStatus(formData) {
        this.authService.postRequestWithFormData('audiocall/twilio/update', formData).subscribe((res) => {
            if (!res['status']) {
                this.toastr.error(res['message']);
            }
        });
    }
    
    callCustomer() {
        var params = { patientPhoneNumber: '+91' + this.phoneNumber };
        this.device.connect(params);
    }

endCall() {
this.device.disconnectAll();
this.dialogRef.close()
//this.modalService.dismissAll();
}

    addMessageCenterData() {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('physicianId', this.user.userId);
        formData.append('patientId', this.selectedPatient.patientId);
        formData.append('appointmentRequest', 'false');
        formData.append('messageType', 'TEXT');
        formData.append('isSenderPhysician', 'true');
        if (this.callStartTime && this.callEndTime) {
            let diff = moment
                .utc(
                    moment(this.callEndTime, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').diff(
                        moment(this.callStartTime, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
                    )
                )
                .format('mm:ss');
            formData.append(
                'messageText',
                'Voice Call | Duration : ' + diff + ' Min'
            );
        }
        if(!this.iserror){
            this.authService.postRequestWithFormData('messagecenter/add', formData).subscribe((res) => {
                if (!res['status']) {
                    this.toastr.error(res['message']);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
    close() {
    this.dialogRef.close()
        //this.modalService.dismissAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't drop full code files of that size into questions here. This will signifiantly lower the chance that you will receive a helpful answer.  This [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) explains how to ask good questions.

They should be as short and concise as possible and ideally have a minimal code example to illustrate the problem.
Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77297011/how-to-transfer-a-call-in-angular-web-app-using-twilio-javascrict-voice-sdk) is basically a copy of what you asked